# How to load database settings dynamically in code igniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, environment, saas

I need to handle already build code on codeigniter. Project is more a REST API backend. Their are two requirements, first database need to be dynamically load from specific http header clientid. So I could have DB like DB_1234, DB_1235. and I need to load DB based on that.

Previous developer use following approach.

1. Remove database configuration from application/database.php
2. Made a helper function with parameter of http header clientid to get db config array for particular client.
3. call helper function in models with `$this->load->database($config, true);` call.

I want to replace it for something better approach than using helper function and push load database code into every model file.

Also I need to added environment based settings So their are also two way code igniter suggesting. Using different folders in config for environment and push config files into there and second for DB specific using multi-dimension array to define environment at that.

So what could be recommended approach. I do not have much exposure of codeigniter.

Helper code

```
function getDbConfig($customer_db) {
    if ($customer_db)
         $customerDatabase = strtolower($customer_db);
    else
         $customerDatabase = 'defaultdb';

    $config['hostname'] = 'localhost';
    $config['username'] = 'root';
    $config['password'] = 'root';
    $config['database'] = 'DB_'.$customerDatabase;
    $config['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
    $config['dbprefix'] = '';
    //$config['port']     = 3306;
    $config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
    $config['db_debug'] = FALSE;
    $config['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $config['cachedir'] = '';
    $config['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $config['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    return $config;
}
```

Model File Code

```
public function __construct() {
    ob_start();
    parent::__construct();
    $this->header = apache_request_headers();
    $config = getDbConfig($this->header['clientid']);
    $this->customDb = $this->load->database($config, true);
}
```

Note: I know code should sanitize and check if db exists before directly try to make connection. That need to be fixed later.

Note: Project will serve one DB at a time for particular request. But that request will have http header clientid which used to determine the database need to be connected. Because there would be n numbers of client and n number of DBs, So multiple db settings in database.php will not work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use two database using codigniter database file by using following code in database.php

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'database' => 'firstdatabase',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => TRUE,
'cachedir' => 'application/cache',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

);

```
$db['seconddatabase'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'database' => 'seconddatabase',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => TRUE,
'cachedir' => 'application/cache',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

);

For using second database the syntax is following.

```
$otherdb = $this->load->database('seconddatabase', TRUE); // the TRUE paramater tells CI that you'd like to return the database object.

$query = $otherdb->select('column_one, column_two')->get('table');
```

Comment: I need to dynamically make connection to DBs. Their would be unknown number of DB. Your approach is recommended for finite and known number of DBs where we need to fetch data from multiple DB at a time. In my case one request would consume only one DB but that DB would be depend on HTTP header variable.